# Using the Pumping Lemma to Prove $L = \{a^ib^jc^k \mid i < j < k\}$ is not Context-Free

Tags: proof-writing, formal-languages, automata, context-free-grammar

I want to use the Pumping Lemma to prove that $$L = \{a^ib^jc^k \mid i < j < k\}$$ is not context-free. I think I have the intuition, but I don't know how to prove it. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For arbitrary $j>1$ take the word $ab^jc^{j+1}$. Since  $ab^jc^{j+1}=a\cdot b\cdot  b^{j-1}\cdot c^{j+1}$ then for all $m$ we have $a\cdot b^m\cdot  b^{m(j-1)}\cdot c^{j+1}\in L$. But it is impossible for $m\ge 2$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a proper application of the Pumping Lemma. In the solution only $b$ is chosen to be pumped, but in fact one should prove there is no possible choice at all, whatever pumping part you take. Also note that the Lemma for context-free languages involves two pumping subwords, and I *can* pump the initial choice $ab^jc^{j+1}$ with two such subwords.

Answer (score 1):

$L=\{a^ib^jc^k|i<j<k\}$ let $n<i$ and $s=uvwxy$ and $s\in L$ then pumping lemma $|vx|>0$ and $|vwx|\leq n$ implies $vwx$ contains either one alphabet ($a$, $b$ or $c$) or two alphabet ($a,b$ or $b,c$) not three alphabets (since $n<i$) let us assume it contains alphabets $a$ and $b$ (i.e $v$ contains $a$ and x contains $b$) by pumping lemma $uv^kwx^ky \in L$ implies $a^{i+k}b^{j+k}c^k \in L$  gives contradiction that $i+k <k $ there fore $L$ is not a CFL